# Inline editable texts with angularjs not update records

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am newbie to angularjs. i am trying to make inline editable text using angularjs and luckily i have made this.. check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cAHz7/456/

but problem is my record is updated inline but it is not update in `$scope` variable.

Comment: your directive doesn't work.  your `data-ng-model` isn't binding to the value, it's binding to the inner html, which isn't the same thing.

Comment: I'm not going to write a directive for you; there isn't a simple fix, the logic is completely wrong.

Comment: Why you using `directive` for this task? you can try with simple text box .

Comment: Ok no problem..i will do this..@Claies

Comment: There is no reason i find this from web search..so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this example plunker  [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/VLKzcd?p=preview)

HTML:

```
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="todo in todos" inline-edit="todo.title" on-save="updateTodo(todo.title)" on-cancel="cancelEdit(todo.title)"></li>
  </ul>
```

DIRECTIVE

```
app.directive('inlineEdit', function($timeout) {
     return {
        scope: {
          model: '=inlineEdit',
          handleSave: '&onSave',
          handleCancel: '&onCancel'
        },
        link: function(scope, elm, attr) {
          var previousValue;    
              scope.edit = function() {
                scope.editMode = true;
                previousValue = scope.model;

                $timeout(function() {
                  elm.find('input')[0].focus();
                }, 0, false);
              };
              scope.save = function() {
                scope.editMode = false;
                scope.handleSave({value: scope.model});
              };
              scope.cancel = function() {
                scope.editMode = false;
                scope.model = previousValue;
                scope.handleCancel({value: scope.model});
              };
            },
            templateUrl: 'inline-edit.html'
          };
```